# i made a many to many relationship between the following tables, have i done it right? secondly i want a join query for them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

i have many to many relationship between the following tables:

```
create table instructors
(i_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
i_name varchar(50), etc...)

create table members
(
m_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
m_name varchar(50, etc...))

create table schedule
(sch_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
sch_session varchar(10))<BR>
-- session is(morning, afternoon, evening)<br>
```

bellow is my junction table

```
create table Ins_Mem_Sch
(ins_mem_sch_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
i_id int not null foreign key references instructors(i_id),
m_id int not null foreign key references members(m_id),
sch_id int not null foreign key references schedules(sch_id)
)
```

i want to know if what i have done so far is right, secondly i tried to join them by query, but i couldn't, maybe its because i haven't practiced joins for many to many relationship, i am not a perfect programmer, so i want a join query to get data from all tables. 
I would appreciate your help.
regards,

Comment: yes the tables looks good, only one thing just remove the primary key from Ins_Mem_Sch its not require, and what kind of data you want to display ?

Comment: thanks for your comment, so you mean that i remove ins_mem_sch_id column completely?, i want to display * members, instructors, and their schedules

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The PRIMARY KEY is absolutely required, just not the ins_mem_sch_id column!

Comment: well its not needed unless your application has a delete operation on `Ins_Mem_Sch` in this case you can keep `ins_mem_sch_id` , since deleting on primary key is faster. But if its not there then just remove it.

Comment: @Strawberry yes PK is absolutely needed for the columns and I gave the reason why in the table `Ins_Mem_Sch` you should keep `ins_mem_sch_id` or why you dont keep `ins_mem_sch_id`

Comment: That's great - but it's not what you said above.

Comment: yeah I did not phrase it properly !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables looks good only thing the last table `Ins_Mem_Sch` does not need a primary key `ins_mem_sch_id`

Now joining these tables are pretty easy. Consider the case when you have rows in the table `Ins_Mem_Sch` with `i_id , m_id and sch_id` you can use the following kind of join

(I am providing MYSQL example since you tagged the question with MYSQL)

```
select 
i.i_name,
m.m_name,
s.sch_session 
from 
Ins_Mem_Sch ims
inner join instructors i on i.i_id = ims.i_id
inner join members m on m.m_id = ims.m_id
inner join schedule s on s.sch_id = ims.sch_id
```

The above is just an example of listing the data matching all the tables.
There are many other situations where you may need to get data as per requirement and without knowing these its hard to comment upon.

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY is a prerequisite of relational tables. In this case, we have a perfectly good NATURAL composite candidate key (i_id,m_id), which can be set as PRIMARY, meaning that the surrogate key is not required.

Comment: thank you very much dear @Abhik Chakraborty, one thing i am still confused, that should i delete the column ins_mem_sch or not

Comment: Ok dear, thanks again for your quick and complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Even your requirement is not clear but you can use of joins in your query as per below:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ins.i_name,mmb.m_name,sch.sch_session 
FROM Ins_Mem_Sch ims 
JOIN instructors ins ON ims.i_id=ins.i_id 
JOIN members mmb ON mmb.m_id=ims.m_id 
JOIN `schedule` sch ON sch.sch_id=ims.sch_id 
WHERE your_col='your_value';
```